# QGIS 3.2 reading real number as string

Tags: qgis-3

I am attempting to import a CSV file as a delimted text layer that has decimal values into QGIS 3.2.  Whenever I do so, instead of QGIS reading the decimal values as real or double, it reads them as strings!

Interestingly, while I was working on the project as a draft prior to saving it, I had no problem with QGIS reading the data properly.  It seems that once I saved the project, QGIS is failing to read my imported decimal values properly.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the numbers inside quotes (ex "4.02") inside your CSV?